# infinity plugin audacious

Tags: dbus, audacious, pkg-config

Hey guys I'm quite new to ubuntu so sorry for asking newbi questions but: I found this interessting visualization plug-in for audacious (http://sourceforge.net/projects/infinity-plugin/) but I have no idea how to compile it. The last two trys caused a systemcrash. 
Can someone please tell me what dependacies are required for the programm to compile...

Thanks in advance

BTW if it helps I get this error: 
configure: error: *** pkg-config not found. See http://www.freedesktop.org/software/pkgconfig/

Hey guys I'm quite new to ubuntu so sorry for asking newbi questions but: I found this interessting visualization plug-in for audacious (http://sourceforge.net/projects/infinity-plugin/) but I have no idea how to compile it. The last two trys caused a systemcrash. 
Can someone please tell me what dependencies are required for the programm to compile...

Thanks in advance

BTW if it helps I get this error: 
configure: error: *** pkg-config not found. See http://www.freedesktop.org/software/pkgconfig/

UPDATE: I found pkg-config. You can install it by using the synaptics package manager. But now it's asking for glib-2.0...which is not listed there...at least not under this exact name.
I've found this thread where someone installed libperl-dev & libgtk2.0-dev (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1607632) and it kinda worked for him. I'm trying that now. I going to give feedback on how it worked for me.

BTW: Thanks for all the replies ;-)

Another UPDATE: So here I am again. BTW libperl-dev & libgtk2.0-dev somehow managed to get the compiling process moving. But only a few lines further :-(. Now, and here is where I've ruined my previous ubuntu installations, it says:

**checking for DBUSGLIB1... no
configure: error: Package requirements (dbus-glib-1 >= 0.92) were not met:
No package 'dbus-glib-1' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.**

The first 3 lines kinda make sense. It was looking for a certain package, namely **dbus-glib-1** , but couldn't find it in my system. 
The weird thing here is: I can't find this one either. I've look almost everywhere. A web search refers me to the package libdbus-glib-1-2 (http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libdbus-glib-1-2) but that one is already installed.

I'm afraid I have to consider figuring out what the second part means. I have to be honest here: I have no idea what i could possibly mean.
Could anyone please give me some sort of hint where to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you had is that the core package dbus-glib-1 was installed (the library itself) but not the **development** package dbus-glib-1-dev (which contains things to compile against the library, for example the header files).
You should install dbus-glib-1-dev.

BTW as of today you can try a new release of [infinity-plugin](https://dprotti.github.io/infinity-plugin/). It depends on less libraries than the one you tried (no dbus, no gtk+) so it's easier to compile.

In Ubuntu you install all the deps with the command:

```
sudo apt -y install pkg-config audacious-dev libsdl2-dev libglib2.0-dev
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`pkg-config` is telling you that it cannot find a file named `dbus-glib-1.pc` so if you already installed `dbus-glib-1-2`, that means that you'll have to tell `pkg-config` where it is via the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable.  You can try the following:

Start by opening a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and typing the command

```
locate dbus-glib-1.pc
```

It should tell you where that file is.  On mine it says `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/dbus-glib-1.pc`  Next type `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (or whatever path your `locate` command output was) making sure to leave off `/dbus-glib-1.pc` from the end of the `locate` output.  `pkg-config` should now be able to find `dbus-glib`.

If the `locate` command doesn't output anything, then dbus-glib is not installed and you'll have to install it using the command `sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2`.  Depending on which version of Ubuntu you're running, you might have to type `apt-cache search dbus-glib-1` and then `sudo apt-get install` a different version than 1-2.  Be sure to avoid the packages that have -dbg , -dev , or -doc at the end of the title.  Those aren't the ones you want.

Good luck.